# Docker installation failed on ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64 on VMware

Tags: 16.04, server, docker

I have installed ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64 server on VMware and when I tried to install docker for installing rancher I am getting the following error.
I used following convenience script for installing docker

```
curl https://releases.rancher.com/install-docker/17.06.sh | sh
```

Console output screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the package configuration, since you're using server, Im afraid you have to modify `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Locate any line containing `cdrom`, once you've found it, you can either comment/delete the line. For example on my 14.04.

From

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release i386 (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted
```

To

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release i386 (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted
```